# Why inverse flattening is zero in esri prj file for spheres?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, ellipsoid

I have a prj file which is assumed to have a sphere datum (not ellipsoid). here is the prj file:

> PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["Popular Visualisation
>   CRS",DATUM["D_Popular_Visualisation_Datum",SPHEROID["Popular_Visualisation_Sphere",6378137,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Mercator"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

I'm interested in this part of this prj file

> SPHEROID["Popular_Visualisation_Sphere",6378137,0]

I expect the third parameter of SPHEROID as the inverse flattening to be infinity for sphere (a=b) but here esri writes zero for this parameter!

```
flattening  = f = (a-b)/a                  //=Zero for Sphere
inverse flattening = 1/f = a/(a-b)         //=Infinity for Sphere
```

**Is there any explanation why esri prj files set the inverse flattening to zero for spheres?**

Comment: How should they write infinity?

Comment: Even if it is hard to find a convention to write infinity they are not allowed to change the meaning of datum. zero inverse flattening can be interpreted as a dot!

Comment: Maybe simply writing "Infinity" was enough as in C# we can read it this way `double.Parse("Infinity")` also other languages may have similar behavior. If not applicable they may try writing the Flattening (not inverse flattening) as the third parameter of the SPHEROID

Comment: There has been many variants of prj file. I am not sure if this is the most current one http://epsg.io/3857 but it looks rather different `PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

Comment: @user30184 Yours is the Esri version, OP's is the first EPSG version, or a mix of EPSG and something else.

Answer (score 6):

Esri first proposed the WKT format for OGC around (estimating) 1998 using what we'd already developed in-house. The SPHEROID format has to support both ellipsoids and spheres. It is easier to allow the second numerical value to be a numerical value rather than have it sometimes be a string (yes, I know it's always a string when parsing it) and sometimes a double value.

It also must support multiple languages (we were using C at the time) so using a string might have had to be handled differently for different languages.

We could have set the second value to be the 'b' (semi-minor axis) instead, but for whatever reason we didn't do that.

Disclosure: I work for Esri.

Comment: It is not the first time I see esri do something in a strange way and don't have any acceptable reason for his did. another example is using UTF8 as the encoding to store attribute values in dbf file and all who have read the dbf file specification knows just fixed two-length encoding is allowed when writing string values in dbf file to the storage.

Comment: correction: fixed two-byte length encodings

Comment: Shapefiles use the dBase III+ specification, which predated both UTF-8 and UTF-16. "Acceptable reason" is in the eye of the beholder; cutting the already limited field name and widths in half  (to 5 and 127) because some characters *might*  be mulibyte seems the unacceptable option to me.

Comment: Also not following a documented specification (dbf) is unacceptable option to me. [link](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000325.shtml)